# Capture the out parameter from stored procedure to pass to shell script

Tags: java, sql, shell, plsql

I am unable to pass out parameter from procedure called through java class to an shell script as shown below.I cannot use the procedure code instead of JAVA in my shell script because this script is going to be used across many regions and the DB credentials vary.Can someone help me on this.

```
#!/bin/ksh
# Setup common environment
. `dirname $0`/db_env.sh

SP_NAME=P_MNR_EE_TMP_CHK
SP_SCHEMA_PROP=utils.miner.user
DB_USER_PROP=utils.miner.user
DB_PASSWD_PROP=utils.miner.password


$JAVA -classpath $CLASSPATH -DCONFIGDIR=${CONFIGDIR} com.mantas.dbtools.util.RunStoredProcedure $DB_USER_PROP $DB_PASSWD_PROP $SP_SCHEMA_PROP $SP_NAME
return $?
```

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is just to print out the parameter on the console (in your java app) and then use something like this:

```
out=`$JAVA -classpath $CLASSPATH -DCONFIGDIR=${CONFIGDIR} com.mantas.dbtools.util.RunStoredProcedure $DB_USER_PROP $DB_PASSWD_PROP $SP_SCHEMA_PROP $SP_NAME`

return $out
```

Comment: Does the value get printed out when you run the java app outside of the script?

Comment: Actually i run the shell script only,I dont use an Java app..from the script I call the java util class which runs the procedure..I get the output in a log in different folder..Basically I am not a java guy so unable to figure out what happens inside..